# Dynamic Programming puzzle: Find longest consecutive pairs of 3 (different) pieces

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

Puzzle: [Xsquare And Chocolates Bars](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/xsquare-and-chocolates-bars-2/description/)

My approach:

3 pieces form 1 set.
Longest consecutive sets needs to be found out such that all pieces in a set are not same.
Then subtract this from total length of chocolate bar.

Start from index 1 (0 based).

### Divide

*Case 1*: If pieces are same, don't consider current index.
Find from next index.

```py
if bar[current - 1] == bar[current] and bar[current] == bar[current + 1]:
    if dp[current + 1] == -1:
        dp[current + 1] = CountConsecutiveSets(current + 1)
    dp[current] = dp[current + 1]
    return dp[current]
```

---

*Case 2*: If pieces are different
*Case 2.1*: Consider current set: Count 1 for the current set & find remaining sets count after the current set.

```py
if dp[current + 3] == -1:
    dp[current + 3] = CountConsecutiveSets(current + 3)
withCurrent = 1 + dp[current + 3]
```

*Case 2.2*: Ignore current set: Find remaining sets from the next current

```py
if dp[current + 1] == -1:
    dp[current + 1] = CountConsecutiveSets(current + 1)
withoutCurrent = dp[current + 1]
```

Because max consecutive set has to be found, find `max(Case 2.1 & Case 2.2)`.

---

### Base Case:

When current is at the last index (or greater than last index), set cannot be formed.
So return 0.

---

---

### Full Code

```py
def CountRemainingCandies(self, bar):
    dp = [-1] * (len(bar) + 2)

    def CountConsecutiveSets(current):
        # Solve small sub-problems
        if current >= len(bar) - 1:
            dp[current] = 0
            return 0

        # Divide
        # Case 1: If same candies
        if bar[current - 1] == bar[current] and bar[current] == bar[current + 1]:
            if dp[current + 1] == -1:
                dp[current + 1] = CountConsecutiveSets(current + 1)
            dp[current] = dp[current + 1]
            return dp[current]

        # Case 2: If different candies
        # Case 2.1: Consider current
        if dp[current + 3] == -1:
            dp[current + 3] = CountConsecutiveSets(current + 3)
        withCurrent = 1 + dp[current + 3]
        # Case 2.2: Ignore current
        if dp[current + 1] == -1:
            dp[current + 1] = CountConsecutiveSets(current + 1)
        withoutCurrent = dp[current + 1]

        # Combine
        dp[current] = max(withCurrent, withoutCurrent)
        return dp[current]

    consecutiveSetsCount = CountConsecutiveSets(1)
    return len(bar) - 3 * consecutiveSetsCount
```

---

---

Test case:

bar = "CCCSCCSSSCSCCSCSSCSCCCSSCCSCCCSCCSSSCCSCCCSCSCCCSSSCCSSSSCSCCCSCSSCSSSCSSSCSCCCSCSCSCSSSCS"
Ans: 39

But above code gives 6.

What's wrong in my thinking & how to fix it?

---

---

---

---

גלעד ברקן's [Top-Down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58219450/4038979) logic:

```py
def CountRemainingCandies(self, bar):
    dp = [-1] * len(bar)

    def CountConsecutiveSets(current):
        # Solve small sub-problems
        if current <= 1:
            dp[0] = dp[1] = 0
            return 0

        # Divide
        # Case 1: Consider current
        # If different candies
        withCurrent = -1
        if bar[current] != bar[current - 1] or bar[current] != bar[current - 2]:
            if current - 3 < 0: current = 0
            if dp[current - 3] == -1:
                dp[current - 3] = CountConsecutiveSets(current - 3)
            withCurrent = 1 + dp[current - 3]

        # Case 2: Ignore current
        if current - 1 < 0: current = 0
        if dp[current - 1] == -1:
            dp[current - 1] = CountConsecutiveSets(current - 1)
        withoutCurrent = dp[current - 1]

        # Combine
        dp[current] = max(withCurrent, withoutCurrent)
        return dp[current]

    consecutiveSetsCount = CountConsecutiveSets(len(bar) - 1)
    return len(bar) - 3 * consecutiveSetsCount
```

I'm using גלעד ברקן's logic but still getting wrong answer for test case
`bar = "CCCSCCSSSCSCCSCSSCSCCCSSCCSCCCSCCSSSCCSCCCSCSCCCSSSCCSSSSCSCCCSCSSCSSSCSSSCSCCCSCSCSCSSSCS"`

Comment: Added working top-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working top-down in Python (`f(str, i)` returns a tuple, `(overall_best, sequence_length_up_to_i`):

```
# Returns the sequence length,
# not the problem answer, which
# is the length of the chocolate
# after removing the sequence.
def f(s, i, memo):
  if i in memo:
    return memo[i]

  if i < 2:
    return (0, 0)

  (best, _) = f(s, i-1, memo)

  if s[i] != s[i-1] or s[i] != s[i-2]:
    seq_len = 3 + f(s, i - 3, memo)[1]
  else:
    seq_len = 0

  memo[i] = (max(best, seq_len), seq_len)
  return memo[i]

s = "CCCSCCSSSCSCCSCSSCSCCCSSCCSCCCSCCSSSCCSCCCSCSCCCSSSCCSSSSCSCCCSCSSCSSSCSSSCSCCCSCSCSCSSSCS"

print(f(s, len(s) - 1, {})[0]) # 51
```

Comment: I didn't understand how to take different `tuple` item in different cases.

Comment: My observations: When pieces are unequal: `tuple[1]`. When skipping current: `tuple[0]`.

Comment: When combining, take max of considering current & skipping current as `tuple[0]` & considering current count as `tuple[1]`.

Comment: @Anil when we consider `f(i - 1)`, we only need the best so far up to `(i - 1)`, which is the first part of the tuple, since we cannot (necessarily) extend that sequence with the current square. When we have a block that works, we want the second part of the tuple from `f(i- 3)`, which is the length of the sequence up to there, so we can test if that extension is better than the overall max so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sequence has to be built of exact blocks of three, we can consider each square just as the third in the last block of the sequence. Note that we can also reduce space to `O(1)` by updating just four cells.

JavaScript code:

```js
// Returns the sequence length,
// not the problem answer, which
// is the length of the chocolate
// after removing the sequence.
function f(s){
  if (s.length < 3)
    return 0

  let dp = new Array(s.length+1).fill(0)
  let best = 0
  
  for (let i=2; i<s.length; i++){
    if (s[i] != s[i-1] || s[i] != s[i-2])
      dp[i+1] = 3 + dp[i-2]
      
    best = Math.max(best, dp[i+1])
  }
  
  return best
}

var strs = [
  "SSSSSSSSS", 
  "CCCCCCCCC",
  "SSSSCSCCC",
  "SSCCSSSCS",
  "CCCSCCSSSCSCCSCSSCSCCCSSCCSCCCSCCSSSCCSCCCSCSCCCSSSCCSSSSCSCCCSCSSCSSSCSSSCSCCCSCSCSCSSSCS"
]

for (let s of strs)
  console.log(f(s))
```

Comment: For easier understanding can you please convert it to Top-Down approach?

Comment: I tried top-down. It's giving same wrong answer. Please refer question's bottom.

Comment: @Anil thanks, the top-down code is returning the wrong answer for the long string but the bottom-up seems to work (90 - 51 = 39). I'll check the top down again.